# statement inside php eval()

Tags: php, eval

In a PHP framework which provides hookpoints that are implemented using eval() I am trying to interrupt or continue a loop from within an eval() call.
This is what I am trying

The framework loops like

```
...
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
    // framweork code here ...
    eval( $plugin_code );
    // framweork code here ...
}
...
```

$plugin_code contains PHP-code - in this sample case

```
if( $i == 5 ) {
    continue;
}
```

It results in this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  'continue' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context
```

If it is true that eval() only evaluates *expressions* and can NOT evaluate *statements* - then how can I implement the continue / break statements inside an eval()?

Comment: `eval` can execute statements. Read the error message, it clearly explains what the problem is.

Comment: `continue;` has to be lexically inside the loop, it can't be done in `eval` or a function.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has said this already: `eval` is the wrong tool for creating "hookpoints" in a framework; run-time evaluated code is fragile, hard to debug, and very easy to make insecure. If this is a framework you are writing, rather than one that you're using, I would strongly advise you to revise this design and look at how other frameworks use callbacks and plugin objects for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your replys. @Barmar I can't see why continue should not be inside the loop.

Comment: @IMSoP You are right - however I do not write the framework but have to use it. So there is no way around using eval unfortunately...

Comment: You can't use it in `eval()` for the same reason you can't put the `continue` statement in a function that you call in the loop. It has to be *textually* inside the looping statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving aside the mechanics of `eval` and `continue` for a moment, I think there is a more fundamental point to make: *when writing code that "plugs in" to another system, you can only do what that system allows you to do*.

If the hook system simply executes the code you give it (whether via `eval`, or a callback function, or any other mechanism), you cannot use it to control the flow of loops etc in the main framework code.

If the framework wanted you to do that, it would have to provide a mechanism for your plugin to signal back to the framework what you want it to do - you might register the plugin in a particular way, return a particular value from the callback, set a particular variable, etc.

If you don't want to directly modify the framework, your only option is to request such a feature from the framework's author.

Comment: Yep - I think you are right. This seems to be the correct answere. There is no way to manipulate that sort of control flow - I see that now. I solved my particular task by working around it and using other hookpoints. It would have been nicer by just "continueing" though :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a statement like `continue` or `break` in `eval()` to affect an outside loop.

I suggest using a variable.

```
$plugin_code = 'if( $i == 5 ) {
    $continue = true;
}';

$continue = false;
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
    eval( $plugin_code );
    if ($continue) {
        continue;
    }
    // other code
}
```

If you also want to skip the rest of the plugin code, it should put that code in an `else` block.

```
$plugin_code = 'if( $i == 5 ) {
    $continue = true;
} else {
    // other code
}';
```

IMHO, this whole thing smells fishy. The plugin is dependent on the specific variable being used for the loop, which is quite fragile.

Comment: This won't work, because assigning a variable `$continue = true` will not change the actual flow of control inside the code being eval'd. Doing `continue` after the eval completes is not equivalent, and `continue` at the end of a loop body does nothing anyway.

Comment: It's obviously a simplification, I assume there's other code after the `eval()` that should be skipped by the `continue`.

Comment: Exactly - it is a simplification and you *should* assume that. The problem is, the rest of the code being eval'd *will* be eval'd, because setting `$continue = true` won't stop it from being eval'd. Doing a `continue` after the eval finishes is too late to have the desired control-flow effect.

Comment: I see you have edited your solution to suggest putting the remainder of the code (after where the `continue` would have been) inside the `for` loop which belongs to the framework code. You are suggesting editing the framework code itself!

Comment: @kaya3 I've also edited it now to show how to construct the plugin to skip the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your replys. It is a simplification. There is no way to edit the framework code - otherwise I would not have to handle this whole eval-thing at all...

Answer (score 0):

Keywords like `continue`, `break` and `return` which affect the control-flow of the program cannot be used directly inside `eval` to achieve the result you want. `eval` is a function, and a function cannot change the control-flow of the code which calls it, except by throwing an exception.

Since `continue` simply means "skip to the next iteration of the loop", and this is equivalent to "don't execute the rest of the code in this block", you could rewrite your code to make the rest of the block conditional on the `if` statement instead. If the code looks like

```php
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
    if( $i == 5 ) {
        continue;
    }
    // do more things
}
```

then this can trivially be rewritten as

```php
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
    if( $i != 5 ) {
        // do more things
    }
}
```

and this is now in a form which can be `eval`'d:

```php
// your code
$plugin_code = 'if( $i = 5 ) {
    // do more things
}';

// framework code
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
    eval($plugin_code);
}
```

However this still only affects the control-flow of the code you're passing into the framework. It's not possible to change the control-flow of the framework code itself.

Comment: How would you put that in the `$plugin_code` hook? The whole idea is that this variable can be used to change the loop dynamically.

Comment: The `$plugin_code` block is the loop body, everything inside the `{`...`}` of the `for` loop. The point here is that if the loop body is in a string being passed to eval, then you *cannot* use a control-flow construct like `continue` so you must achieve the control-flow effect you desire by other means, such as an `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks. I can't write anything into the framework code unfortunately...

Comment: You don't need to edit the framework code. I'll make an edit to make this clearer.

Comment: @kaya3 That won't work. The part you entitled "// do more things" is in the framework. I cannot pull that code into my plugin.

Comment: I see, and you've edited the question to clarify that. In that case what you want to achieve isn't possible, unfortunately.